# Appropriate sample size for model validation with RMSE errors

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, sample-size

I have been looking over the internet for a way to determine the appropriate sample size for a validation experiment that validates the RMSE results from a deep learning (CNN) model.

The network was evaluated with 40 subjects and resulted in a mean and standard deviation for the error ( mean of 5 and standard deviation of 2 ).

I want to determine how many samples I need to have a 95% confidence in the results.

There are numerous functions out there that are telling me different results, and I am not sure which to use or what would be an appropriate sample size.

I am also pretty new to research statistics. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you have 40 observations in your data? If so, that is not enough for a neural network, in general. Also, if you are interested in confidence intervals you may be better off using a more statistical model which is better suited for this.

Comment: My data set had about 400 observations and I tested with 10% of the data

Comment: Why are you using a NN? Why not a regression model? I don't know if you can make any such statements on a CNN.